# Aligning variables and comments in vim

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, alignment

I've looked for this since a long time but I can't seem to find anything relating to this. It could be because of my poor searching skills.

Whenever the code starts getting long, its obvious that we have hard time reading it, specially unaligned variable declarations or comments. Is there a way (maybe a plugin) to auto format my indentations and align variable declarations and comments?

Changing something like this

[image]

To this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use the [vim_easy_align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) plugin.

With the plugin installed select the lines that you would like to fix and run the command:

```
:'<,'>EasyAlign /--/
```

I you prefer [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) the corresponding command is:

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /--/
```

Comment: I use [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) for this; I'm not sure what the exact differences with easy_align are, but it seems roughly similar.